# Crashlytics manual update to 3.8.4 causing linker errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crashlytics

I have a very old legacy project (Dating somewhere from 2010). Its Crashlytics kit was last updated somewhere during 2013.

I was trying to update it. It doesn't use pods so I used the [official Manual update](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/update?type=manual) guide.

1. I downloaded the updated kits.
2. Replaced the old Crashlytics with new one as suggested. The old one didn't have a Fabric kit so I just pasted it there and linked the library in Project settings.

These are the only two steps described there. But doing that causes linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      +[CLSDemangleOperation demangleBlockInvokeCppSymbol:] in Crashlytics(CLSDemangleOperation.o)
      +[CLSDemangleOperation demangleSwiftSymbol:] in Crashlytics(CLSDemangleOperation.o)
      -[CLSDemangleOperation main] in Crashlytics(CLSDemangleOperation.o)
      ___28-[CLSDemangleOperation main]_block_invoke in Crashlytics(CLSDemangleOperation.o)
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in Crashlytics(CLSDemangleOperation.o)
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__pointer_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for std::exception const* in Crashlytics(CLSException.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in Crashlytics(CLSException.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      CLSTerminateHandler() in Crashlytics(CLSException.o)
      ___clang_call_terminate in Crashlytics(CLSException.o)
  "std::get_terminate()", referenced from:
      _CLSExceptionCheckHandlers in Crashlytics(CLSException.o)
  "typeinfo for char const*", referenced from:
      GCC_except_table1 in Crashlytics(CLSException.o)
  "typeinfo for std::bad_alloc", referenced from:
      GCC_except_table1 in Crashlytics(CLSException.o)
  "typeinfo for std::exception", referenced from:
      GCC_except_table1 in Crashlytics(CLSException.o)
      typeinfo for std::exception const* in Crashlytics(CLSException.o)
  "___cxa_current_exception_type", referenced from:
      CLSTerminateHandler() in Crashlytics(CLSException.o)
  "___cxa_rethrow", referenced from:
      CLSTerminateHandler() in Crashlytics(CLSException.o)
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for std::__1::__basic_string_common<true> in Crashlytics(CLSException.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      CLSTerminateHandler() in Crashlytics(CLSException.o)
  "___cxa_demangle", referenced from:
      +[CLSDemangleOperation demangleCppSymbol:] in Crashlytics(CLSDemangleOperation.o)
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in Crashlytics(CLSException.o)
  "std::set_terminate(void (*)())", referenced from:
      _CLSExceptionInitialize in Crashlytics(CLSException.o)
      CLSTerminateHandler() in Crashlytics(CLSException.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Things I have tried:

1. Removing both references of Crashlytics and Fabrics and relinking them.
2. Removing physical instances of both kits and readding them.
3. Cleaning derived data of XCode.
4. Cleaning the project.
5. Installing latest version via Cocoapods.
6. Upgrading via Fabric App

But the errors persist. Right now, I am at my wits end. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Sounds strange. I am working on a similar project (no pods) but usually it is not much hassle to update Fabrics. Are both frameworks included for the target in use ?

Comment: @user3752049 Yes. There are four targets in my project and they are both included in all of them (That's what I meant by relinking/readding them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem was, the previous guy had modified the linker and compiler flags and removed the `$(inherited)` flag from them which was overriding the Cocoapods configs which in turn caused failure in linking main project with Cocoapods and therefore missing symbols as XCode couldn't find the symbols without linking.

First I removed the manual Crashlytics and then installed them via cocoapods. Now it said that symbols were missing.

To fix this:

1. Go to "Preprocessor Macros" and make sure `$(inherited)` is added to both debug and release configs.
2. Go to "Other Linker Flags" and make sure `$(inherited)` flag is added there as well.

Crashlytics 3.8.4 is now up and running.